# Query string takes extra character while passing it into the href in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, query-string

I am passing a parameter in the query string in href in JSP. so after when I click on the link it gives some extra character along with the parameter value.

```
String s="approved";
String activationcode=request.getParameter("activationcode");
if(activationcode!=null)
{
try
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","up78cp5317");  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();   
    stmt.execute("update (select Approval.status as st from Approval join Activity on Activity.userid=Approval.id where Activity.activationcode='"+activationcode+"') up set up.st='"+s+"'");
    //stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE ( SELECT Approval.STATUS AS st FROM Approval JOIN Activity ON Activity.userid = Approval.id WHERE Activity.activationcode = '"+activationcode+"') up SET up.st = '"+s+"'");
    //stmt.executeUpdate("update (select Approval.status as st from Approval join Activity on Activity.userid=Approval.id where Activity.activationcode='"+activationcode+"') up set up.st='"+s+"'");      
    //stmt.executeUpdate("delete from activity where activationcode='"+activationcode+"'");
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
```

after clicking on the link I got is this:
http://localhost:8090/TL/OnlineApprovalButton.jsp?activationcode=%2780f91f53-918f-45c4-9ee6-9eda9c40f72d%27

here %27 is adding in head and trail of the parameter value

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replace the string and after that trim the string.

```
String activationcode=request.getParameter("activationcode").repalceAll("'"," ").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of activation code might be starting with apostrophe (') and when you perform url encode of apostrophe it results in %27. You can find url encoding of different characters here. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: yes, you are right. please let me guide how I can correct this.